# Javascript access array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to access certain values in an array, using developer console I have printed out the array and looked at the structure of the array, however I am unsure as to how I can access these values.

```
var position = ctrack.getCurrentPosition();
console.log(position);
```

Below you can see a close up from [my console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bpyV.png):

[image: The console message]

[image: The array]

The developer console looks like this. So say I wanted to access the third entry which is open on the image and get out the values of 0 and 1 and print just them to console. How would I achieve this?

Comment: Your console screen capture is much too small to read. Try using a jsFiddle to allow us to see all of your JS.

Comment: Have you tried `position[3][0]`, `position[3][1]`?

Comment: DevLshOne - Right click copy image Location http://i.stack.imgur.com/1bpyV.png

Ismail - are you suggesting this : console.log(position[3][0] + position[3][1]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to access it by

```
  position[3][0] // and 
  position[3][1];
```

Comment: This structure did the job with "position" instead of "array"

Comment: Yes I'm sorry for the confusion, I didn't notice, my intention was to say something like   arrayName[3][0], it's a more clear example